# Facebook Page Default Landing Tab is NOT WORKING

Tags: tabs, facebook-page

I've been looking for an answer everywhere and cannot find the answer to this, I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I created a custom tab for my page, and I set the default landing tab for the page to this custom tab, however whenever you visit the page it just goes straight to the wall.

I don't want people visiting my page to land on my wall, I want them to land on the custom tab, that's why I created it.

How do I get the default landing tab option to work for my pages?  They're all doing this.

Answer (score 5):

If you already "like" the page (or are an admin), it will always take you to the wall.  If you are not a fan or an admin, it will show you the tab specified.  That is how these tabs work, there is not an always to always show the tab for fans.